# Developing my own virtual keyboard for Windows 7 Desktop

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, keyboard

I would like to build my own virtual keyboard for my windows 7 tablet.
I am not starting from zero in programming; I just have no idea on where to start to make a system level device like a virtual keyboard.

Is there a good article or SDK for this?

Comment: There's two approaches to this: write a program that sends keystrokes to other programs (`SendKeys`), or write a program combined with a device driver that acts like an actual physical keyboard. The latter is much more difficult, but allows some scenarios that `SendKeys` doesn't permit.

Comment: Sendkeys won't work since it doesn't trigger a key interupt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to write a driver in order to truly get a virtual keyboard. Keyboard drivers cannot be written in C#.

Drivers are written in C (not even C++; just C), and they use the [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg581061) for development. There is insufficient documentation, period (the sooner you admit this, the better). Pick up a copy of the following books if you don't already have them: [Windows Internals](http://tinyurl.com/64mr8zc), [Advanced Windows Debugging](http://tinyurl.com/6ld6jam), Oney's [Programming the Windows Driver Model](http://tinyurl.com/6ksoaer), and [Developing Drivers with the Windows Driver Foundation](http://tinyurl.com/6etxbfm). I strongly recommend using [KMDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463279.aspx), since it makes writing drivers only extremely difficult rather than insanely near-impossible. Subscribe to [OSR's NTInsider](http://www.osronline.com/) and read their mailing list archives (they are the only source I know that has all the missing details on driver writing). Begin working your personal contacts because there's a medium-to-high chance you'll need to talk to someone deep within Microsoft.

To be brutally honest, it is a lot easier to hire an existing expert in the field. Driver development is *not* cheap, but it's cheaper than doing it yourself.

Comment: Final decision: The whole issue is made moot with the release of Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an old C++ article on the matter.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/onscreenkeyboard.aspx?display=PrintAll&fid=500&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=1605922

But I think you'll wind up using SendKeys in C# - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SendKeys.aspx

Comment: After a cursory look at the C++ solution, it merits more investigation. Thx.